# How would you expect a revisions system to work?

Tags: version-control, versioning, revision

I need to keep a revision system of changes. My question isn't the structure but the behavior.

For example, let's say you are working on a webpage in a code editor. How often would you make a revision for the developer as he's coding the page? Do you save when he saves? Do you save every hour? How many revisions should you keep?

What behavior would you expect in this scenario?

**Update:** 
It seems that it makes a difference if the content is saved online versus saved locally. In my project it's saved online like, WordPress posts or Google docs. I can save locally to the cache or even to a directory on the users computer if they use the desktop software.

Comment: I would expect it to only "commit" (create a revision) when it was asked to do so (not automatically). I would expect it to keep all revisions from the beginning of time. Have you looked at existing systems (git, Mercurial, SVN, CVS, etc)?

Comment: I've used all of them but Mercurial. Hmm... In WordPress and GMail, Google Docs it auto saves every 15 seconds or on keypress respectively. With versioning systems it's manual. However, WP and Google software are both online and don't save copies locally. If the code editor saved documents online would you change from manual to automatic?

Comment: Auto-save is great of course, as is unlimited undo. But I would not call that a revision control system. Especially when editing web sites, working on the files and actually publishing (going live) should be separate steps. Note that GMail saves a draft. It does not send the email automatically.

Comment: You should learn how version-control works, basic concepts at least. The question does not make any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are versioning, you:

- make sure that teammates will not override each-other's work
- write a version diary for future use to be able to handle any scenario

Since it is possible that at some remote time in the future you will need to roll back, it is better to make sure that upon looking at the commit messages, you will be able to determine easier where to roll back. Also, commit messages are helping your teammates to determine what did you do. As a result, my advice is that you should make a commit whenever you have completed a small part of your work, so your commits should be atomic and their message should be speaking for themselves.

Comment: I like this suggestion. I think making revisions manually and with a commit message is better than making timed backups with no distinct message at all.